# Database design for food ordering system on time restaurant?

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, database, database-design, server

I need some help designing the database of a food ordering system.For customer,they do not must login to make order.Im designing a food ordering system that integrate with web,app and POS system.Customer will use a link that provide at restaurant to make order.For the waiter,they will use an app to take order.They will be a person incharge to confirm the order from customer before through to POS and kitchen.So i need help for designing the database.

**Customer**

- Customer_id (PK)
- Order_id (FK)

**Waiter**

- Waiter_id (PK)
- Waiter_name
- Waiter_position
- Waiter_age
- Waiter_phonenum
- waiter_password
- Order_id(FK)

**Menu**(this is menu category)

- Menu_id (PK)
- Menu_category

**Submenu**

- Submenu_id(PK)
- Submenu_name
- Submenu_size
- Submenu_price
- Submenu_quantity

**Order**

- Order_id (PK)
- Customer_id (FK)
- Waiter_id (FK)
- Submenu_id (FK)
- Order_quantity
- Total_price

How should I make it in such a way that a customer can order a different type of food with a different quantity for food and drinks but together in Order Table ?

It is my database design is true?I really sure that something is not perfect yet..

Comment: Typically, you'd have a table of orders, and a table of order_details. You wouldn't normally store the age of a waiter

Comment: Need to see the `SELECT` statements to judge whether a schema is good.